# Invalid type conversion using static_cast, what proper casting should I use?

Tags: c++, casting, typedef, static-cast

I have a type definition of `typedef vector<Object*> ObjList;` I also have a function `vector<BigObject*>* ObjectBox::getBigObjectList();`. `BigObject` is inhertied from `Object`

What I wanted to do is to get a `vector<BigObject*>*` from `getBigObjectList()` and convert it to `vector<Object*>*`, which is an upward casting, and this type is defined as `ObjList` so I basically wanted to to conver that into a `ObjList` type

I tried two ways, the first is

```
ObjList *normalObjectList = (ObjList*) box->getBigObjectList();
```

This compiles and I read from this article ([When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used)) which says C-style casting is rarely desireable since it can be develped into a `reinterpret-cast`

Then I try to use `static_cast`, but I got an error saying Invalid type conversion

```
ObjList *normalObjectList = static_cast<ObjList*> (box->ClipObjectInRect());
```

Neither will this work

```
ObjList *normalObjectList = static_cast<vector<Object*>*> (box->ClipObjectInRect());
```

Why isn't this working? Is this because `static_cast` can only be used to cast a direct class (like `Object` itself) instead of a nested one (I'm just totally guessing here)? What should I do in this case?

Comment: static_cast cant cast to unrelated types

Comment: @DenisErmolin I don't know what you exactly mean by unrelated-types since they are vectors of inherited types and is explicitly defined using `typedef`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning has a very usual flaw; I think we all have made the same mistake sometime. You are thinking of `std::vector<>` as just an output container because this is how you want to use it now, but it is not.

Just imagine that the following code would compile:

```
vector<BigObject*>* bigVector = box->ClipObjectInRect(); // OK
ObjList* objVector = static_cast<ObjList*>(bigVector);   // Not OK; we'll now see why
objVector->push_back(new SmallObject()); // OUCH
```

As you can see, allowing that cast would allow you to try to put a `SmallObject*` in what can only contain `BigObject*`. This would surely result in a runtime error.

By the way: you can actually cast between arrays of related types. This is a behaviour inherited from C. And it results in runtime errors :)

Answer (score 15):

Static cast will also fail if the compiler doesn't know (or is pretending not to know) about the relationship between the types.  If your inheritance isn't declared **public** between the two, the compiler will consider them as unrelated types and give you the same cryptic warning.

This just bit me, so thought I'd share.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think you might need to cast each individual object in the vector. I would try overloading getBigObjectList() to return an ObjList*. So your overloaded function would look something like

```
ObjList* ObjectBox::getBigObjectList()
{
 vector<Object*> return_vec
 for(vector<BigObject*>::iterator itr = ObjectBox.bigObjectList.begin(); itr != ObjectBox.bigObjectList.end(); itr++)
 {
  return_vec.push_back(static_cast<Object*> (itr));
 }
 return return_vec
}
```

Any particular reason you're describing your vector as a list? Or using a vector instead of a list in the first place?

EDIT: Basically, what Denis said.